# How to set the values of a delegate's parameters to use for subsequent calls without supplying them each time?

Tags: c#, parameters, delegates, refactoring, method-call

In C#, is there a way to create a delegate with a value, e.g. "MyDelegate("Hello World")", which can be stored in a variable, and then later be invoked with the value it has been given?

For example: (I know this is not how delegates work, it's just pseudocode to make it clearer what I'm looking for)

```
delegate void MyDelegate(string text);

void WriteText(string text) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(text)
}

MyDelegate newDelegate = WriteText("Hello World") //Store the function and a string value 

newDelegate.InvokeWithOwnValue() //Invoke the delegate with the string value that we've given it before

//Output: "Hello World"
```

I don't know if this is even possible with Delegates, or if there is actually something else I'm looking for.

Comment: You could also look int Action and Func, they are easier to work with

Comment: Maybe you should explain more about your use case... maybe delegates are not the right way to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can capture the value by using a lambda**, but you would need a different delegate type, as now you would be invoking with no parameters.

It's a lot easier to just use the various `Action` and `Func` delegate types.

```cs
void WriteText(string text) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(text);
}
```

```cs
Action newDelegate = () => WriteText("Hello World"); //Store a string value 

newDelegate(); //Invoke the delegate with the string value that we've given it before

//Output: "Hello World"
```

```cs
Action<string> originalDelegate = WriteText;  // if you already have a delegate

Action newDelegate = () => originalDelegate("Hello World"); //Store the delegate and a string value 

newDelegate(); //Invoke the delegate with the string value that we've given it before

//Output: "Hello World"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [closures](https://www.simplethread.com/c-closures-explained/).

```
Action newDelegate = () => WriteText("Hello World");
newDelegate();
```